# Pourquoi trente-six ?

Tags: expressions, nombres, origine-ou-raison

Le nombre 36 apparaît dans plusieurs expressions :

> Voir trente-six chandelles. (Être sonné, KO.)
>
> Tous les trente-six du mois. (Jamais)
>
> Il n'y a pas trente-six solutions. (Il y a une, éventuellement deux, solutions.)
>
> Faire trente-six choses à la fois.

Et la liste est probablement incomplète.

*Trente-six* semble être utilisé pour dire « beaucoup ». Est-ce juste une valeur arbitraire ?

Y a-t-il d'autres valeurs typiques et récurrentes dans la langue française ? Pouvez-vous fournir une explication ou une origine ?

Comment: Je pense à une autre qui m'a toujours intrigué: ["22, voilà les flics"](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/22,_v'l%C3%A0_les_flics_!). (Notons que dans l'article Wikipedia, parmi les 9 explications fournies, il n'y a que le premier qui tient un peu la route à mon avis).

Comment: Sur http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/36_%28nombre%29 on lit que: "Ce nombre est parfois synonyme de beaucoup" mais ça ne nous aide pas 36.

Comment: En tous cas, c'est vieux: http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/trente-six voire très vieux http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/trente-six

Comment: _Ne pas y aller par **[quatre](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wiktionary/fr/wiki/ne_pas_y_aller_par_quatre_chemins)** chemins_

Comment: @Joubarc, merci. Du coup, j'ai remplacé par autre chose ;-)

Comment: Ça n'a pas l'air de se rencontrer beaucoup à l'écrit, vu que « trente-six » et « trente-cinq » sont assez proches dans [le corpus Google Ngram French](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=trente+six%2Ctrente+cinq&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3) (et au passage je me demande pourquoi 35 l'emporte de plus en plus depuis environ 1950).

Comment: Et je lance un bonus, spécifiquement pour en savoir plus sur l'historique de *trente-six* pour vouloir dire *beaucoup*.

Comment: La semaine des 35 heures, peut-être?

Comment: Une liste d'expressions en français avec des chiffres/nombres: http://villemin.gerard.free.fr/aCulture/Culture/OnzeExpr.htm

Comment: Vous pouvez visiter ce site pour voir encore une autre expression - http://qc.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070430164955AA5XJLc

Comment: Être au trente-sixième dessous (très inquiet).
Trente-six métiers, trente-six misères…

Comment: A cette question je répondrais [42](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_grande_question_sur_la_vie,_l%27univers_et_le_reste).

Comment: Finissons-en, coupons la poire en deux !

Answer (score 41):

Ce [PDF](http://www.mom.fr/image_carto/ServiceImage/loret/loret_0990-5952_1996_bul_10/PDF/loret_0990-5952_1996_bul_10_p7-20.pdf)<sup>1</sup> soutient mon postulat de départ: les 36 [décans](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9can) en sont probablement à l'origine.

L'extrait :

> <sup>Venons en, maintenant, à ce qui peut arriver brutalement à tout un chacun lorsqu'il éprouve un grand éblouissement à la suite d'une chute ou d'un traumatisme, tel un coup sur la tête. Il est de règle, dit-on, de s'exclamer lorsqu'on revient à soi : “J'ai vu trente-six chandelles !”. Parfois raccourcie ou amplifiée, cette formule, a priori bizarre par le choix de trente-six, perd beaucoup de sa vigueur lorsqu'elle est abrégée en “voir des chandelles” ou grossie jusqu'à “mille chandelles”. À nouveau, via les Grecs et les Romains, l'expression nous vient en droite ligne de la Vallée du Nil.</sup>
>
> <sup>L'Égypte du passé, plus encore que les Babyloniens, a apporté à la définition du temps un soin extrême. Toute la science de ses prêtres astronomes s'est d'abord attachée à la définition de l'heure ; les observations nocturnes permirent ainsi d'établir le rythme diurne des douze heures que suivent douze heures de nuit débouchant sur notre conception, prétendument moderne, du “jour” de vingt-quatre heures. De leurs longues veilles dans l'obscurité et de l'observation du lever d'étoiles spécifiques dans les cantons géométriques d'un cercle de 360º résultant des 36 divisions théoriques qu'ils avaient calculées formant un arc de 10º chacune, dès le III<sup>e</sup> millénaire avant note ère, les astronomes de la Vallée avaient, par là, défini les trente-six décans du ciel que connaît toujours notre zodiaque.</sup>
>
> <sup>Selon l'expression même qu'utilisaient les sacerdotes “observateurs du ciel” (*baq pet*), terme rendu dans les textes grecs à partir des Lagides par le vocable “horoscopes” équivalent à “observateurs de l'heure”, le “travail” de l'étoile se levant, brillant puis se couchant dans le décan de la zone observée du ciel selon la période de l'année définissait pour eux une durée de temps nocturne. À partir de là, l'on établit puis compléta régulièrement des tables horaires de référence. Ceci, résultant de la mise en place des trente-six décans célestes, eut pour conséquence, l'année nocturne étant de 360 “jours”, la définition d'une semaine de dix jours, réglée sur le nombre de divisions internes du cercle théorique d'observation des étoiles ; l'année solaire qu'il fallait naturellement compléter adjoignait à son comput les cinq jours supplémentaires, les “jours en plus de l'an” ou épagomènes.</sup>
>
> <sup>Qui aurait imaginé, alors, que les révolutionnaires français de 1792 remettraient la décade à l'honneur, joueraient aux quilles ou au pharaon le *décadi*, croyant devoir aux Grecs “républicains” et à leur mois de trois décades ce qu'ils devaient, en fait, aux vieux Égyptiens enracinés dans leur idéal monarchique !</sup>
>
> <sup>C'étaient ainsi trente-six *luminaires*, étoiles ou planètes décanales, que des yeux d'hommes dépourvus de tout moyen optique artificiel d'observation allaient scruter des siècles durant. De quoi, certes, être ébloui et, parfois même, y perdre la vue. Curieusement les observateurs du ciel du temps des Pharaons, malgré la vaste littérature conservée par les traités médicaux sur les maladies oculaires, n'ont pas laissé à la postérité le souvenir ou la plainte des tourments oculaires que beaucoup durent éprouver en avançant en âge. Il faut attendre leurs successeurs, astrologues, mages, devins astraux pour voir, dans leurs écrits, les maladies des yeux attribuées en vrac aux dieux sidéraux. Eux seuls étaient cause de tous les troubles visuels y compris ceux dont souffraient leurs interprètes… Et parfois, comme ils en arrivaient à voir, de même que les patients qu'ils prétendaient traiter, “trente-six” ou “mille chandelles”, c'étaient aux nébuleuses formées d'étoiles à peine distinctes, obnubilant la vision, qu'ils attribuaient l'action la plus nocive. Tombant du ciel, ceci valait bien un coup sur la tête !</sup>

<sup>1</sup> J.-Cl. Goyon, *Les nombres consacrés*, 11-13.

Comment: Très intéressant pour ces chandelles ! Ce serait bien d'arriver à trouver la référence de la note 11 (Franz Cumont, L'Égypte des astrologues, p. 173-174). Par contre, on ne peut peut-être pas en conclure que tous les trente-six viennent de là quand même ?

Answer (score 14):

Voilà la seule piste que j'ai pu trouver sur [un forum](http://fr.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20060725000523AA9AfMc) :

> Selon le Petit Robert, 36 est un "nombre utilisé familièrement pour
>   désigner un grand nombre indéterminé". Multiple de 12 (utilisé comme
>   unité dans "une douzaine d’œufs") 36 remonte, dixit la Maison de la
>   Francité spécialiste de la langue française, au système duodécimal (=
>   par 12) de la civilisation babylonienne, dont on situe l’époque vers
>   4000 avant J.-C.  Premiers à observer le mouvement des astres, à leur
>   donner un nom, ils ont été aussi les premiers à avoir découpé
>   l’écliptique en 12 parties égales (= les signes du zodiaque) et le
>   jour en 12 heures en vertu de leur manière de compter par 12. On sait
>   qu’ils comptaient également sur base de leurs 10 doigts, mais le
>   système duodécimal était plus pratique, 10 se divisant par 2 et par 5,
>   tandis que 12 se divise par 2, 3, 4 et 6.

Peut être hors sujet, mais j'ai également trouvé un site référençant les différentes apparitions du nombre 36 : http://membre.oricom.ca/sdesr/nb36.htm

Comment: La question n'est pas à propos du nombre 36, mais à propos de son utilisation dans des expressions. Ces « exemples » n'expliquent en rien pourquoi le nombre 36 a pris la signification de « beaucoup ». Je dirais qu'au contraire, plus un nombre apparaît fréquemment, moins il est souhaitable de le rendre ambigu en lui donnant un nouveau sens.

Comment: Je pense qu'il y a quand même une piste: en cela que le système duodécimal était encore très fréquent vers l'époque médiévale (où certaines de ces expressions ont du naître) et "3 fois 12" serait alors un exemple de "plus grand nombre" pouvant venir à l'esprit de n'importe qui (à une époque ou le calcul n'était pas une science très répandue)... à comparer avec "cent", "mille", "millions" etc. de notre époque.

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez : certes, le lien sur le nombre 36 n'explique pas l'origine, mais je trouvais intéressant de recenser diverses utilisations, pour ce qui est de l'origine, la seule piste que j'ai pu trouvé est celle du système duodécimal, maintenant, ce n'est qu'une piste ;)

Comment: @Dave&Cédric good point ;-) Il Faudrait savoir comment le système duodécimal fonctionnait à l'écrit et à l'oral. Si c'est de la pure base 12, '30' reste douteux en tant que plus grand nombre envisageable. Mais c'est une bonne piste, en effet!

Comment: Ca reste quand même de la spéculation... Pour le même prix, on pourrait dire que "6" voulait dire "beaucoup" parce qu'on ne sait pas le montrer avec une main; et que donc 6 fois 6 est un choix logique pour "vraiment beaucoup"

Comment: Juste pour complémenter : les multiples de six me semblent une particularité du français parmi les langues latines. Dans d'autres langues (portugais et espagnol par exemple), il me semble que les multiples de 5 ou 10 soient plus fréquents. Éventuellement, les multiples de 7 aussi (notamment 49), sans doute à cause de l'influence chrétienne.

Answer (score 10):

Selon le *Dictionnaire des Expressions et Locutions figurées* (les usuels du Robert) :
 « Tous les trente-six du mois (jamais, ou très peu souvent), c'est à dire aussi peu souvent qu'un mois a trente-six jours, par référence plaisante à une division imaginaire du temps, basée cependant sur 12, c'est à dire jamais. »

J'ajouterais qu'on retrouve cette référence, à la fois au calendrier et à jamais, dans les  expressions « aux calendes grecques » qui se comprend dans l'emploi actuel comme une division du temps qui n'a plus cours, à une date qui ne reviendra jamais.

Parmi les expressions qui comportent un nombre particulier, il y a aussi « la semaine des quatre jeudis » pour dire jamais : impossibilité d'une semaine avec quatre jours semblables, et peut-être aussi dans la première moitié du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle, rêve d'une semaine de vacances non prévue, le jeudi étant le jour où les écoliers n'avaient pas cours.

Autre expression utilisée comme un intensif et contenant un nombre : « être sur son trente-et-un » (mettre ses plus beaux habits), dans le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* Alain Rey suggère que c'est peut-être une allusion portant sur le jour excédant le compte des jours d'un mois « normal » (de trente jours).

Comment: Pour les calendes grecques, la vraie raison est qu'elles n'ont jamais existé, puisque les calendes sont un terme romain...

Answer (score 5):

Le *Dictionnaire des expressions et locutions* précise simplement : « La valeur générale de ce multiple de douze est celle d'un intensif ».

Answer (score 3):

## Dans la littérature française (*Les Misérables*, Victor Hugo)

L'expression "Tous les 36 du mois" apparait dans *Les Misérables* (Victor Hugo en 1862) :

> — Nous sommes un petit pays. J’ai bien là sous la remise, ajouta le charron, une vieille calèche qui est à un bourgeois de la ville qui me l’a donnée en garde et qui s’en sert **tous les trente-six du mois**. Je vous la louerais bien, qu’est-ce que cela me fait ? mais il ne faudrait pas que le bourgeois la vît passer ; et puis, c’est une calèche, il faudrait deux chevaux.
>
> **Source :** (Victor Hugo, *Les Misérables*, 1862, [2e partie, livre 7, chap. 5, p. 449](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Hugo_-_Les_Mis%C3%A9rables_Tome_I_%281890%29.djvu/457))

## Un aspect mathématique

> Pour finir, on peut voir sur [wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/36_%28nombre%29) que 36 a de nombreuses
>   propriétés mathématiques puisqu'il est, entre autre :
>
> - le carré de 6 ainsi qu'un nombre triangulaire, ce qui en fait un nombre carré triangulaire
> - un nombre 13-gonal et un nombre hautement composé
> - la somme des cubes des trois premiers nombres entiers
> - la somme des nombres de 1 à 8 (1 + 2 + 3 + … + 8) Et comme la somme de tous les nombres de 1 à 36 (1 + 2 + 3 + … + 35 + 36) donne 666,
>     nombre hautement symbolique, peut-être que 36 est plus complexe et
>     plus grand qu'il n'en à l'air, d'où son sens répandu d'exagération ?
>
> **Source** : http://www.guichetdusavoir.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=47043

Comment: 36 est aussi un nombre symbole dans le bouddhisme tibétain qui met 108 (3x36) au sommet... mais je doute que cela ait influencé l'expression française, le français tire assez peu ses expressions comportant des nombre des mathématiques, mais des références aux étoiles, au calendrier, aux prévisions astrologiques ou à des sources religieuses Le livre biblique des nombres par exemple, le nombre de disciples..) ou gréco-romaines.

Answer (score 2):

Histoire de rêver et de refaire le monde :

- 3 calendes (source du mot calendrier) de 10 jours par mois,
- 12 mois dans l'année pourraient faire remonter aux 36 chandelles...

... s'il était d'usage d'allumer une chandelle tous les dix jours... pour s'attirer la faveur des dieux sur la dizaine à venir !

On verrait ainsi les 36 derniers événements importants de l'année écoulée, défiler dans son crâne lorsque ce dernier à pris un coup imprévu...
... d'autres revoient leur vie défiler à une vitesse folle lors d'épreuves extrêmes.

On a longtemps compté sur ses 12 phalanges avec la pointe du pouce, ce modèle reste encore dans les mesures anglaises : un mois c'est deux mains plus deux doigts, parfois une ou deux phalange en moins, parfois une en plus, mais compter le mois sur trois mains cela n'arrive jamais, il n'y a donc pas de 36 du mois,
... ni d'ailleurs 36 solutions pour résoudre un problème réel quand on compte sur ses phalanges !

36 est aussi un nombre important dans le tantrisme tibétain, il indique un seuil, une étape dans ce que l'on décompte, le summum étant 108 (3x36).

Comment: En parlant des mesures anglaises, il y a aussi 36 pouces dans nos « yards » et (peut-être plus important ?) 36 (pouces) ‘figure[nt]’ deux fois dans les mesures de ‘nos’ « femmes idéales » (**36** - 24 - **36**) !

Answer (score 1):

Il s'agit probablement d'une référence à la fête juive de **Hannouka** (qui tombe généralement au mois de décembre). Pendant cette fête, les personnes de confession juive allument une bougie chaque soir pendant **8 jours** et augmentent le nombre d'une bougie supplémentaire chaque soir suivant, nous avons ainsi (la bougie qui aide à allumer la bougie du soir ne compte pas dans le nombre de bougies de la fête) :

- 1 bougie allumée le premier soir
- 2 bougies allumées le second soir
- 3 bougies allumées le troisième soir
- 4 bougies allumées le quatrième soir
- 5 bougies allumées le cinquième soir
- 6 bougies allumées le sixième soir
- 7 bougies allumées le septième soir
- 8 bougies allumées le huitième soir

**Au total nous avons bien 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 = 36 bougies!

L'expression avoir vu 36 chandelles correspond bien au 36 bougies**. CQFD

Comment: Bonjour et bienvenue sur French Language ! Merci pour cette réponse, mais as-tu d'autres éléments pour confirmer cette hypothèse ?