# Se mettre sur son 31

Tags: expressions, nombres

En ces périodes de fêtes de fin d'années beaucoup d'entre nous se sont **mis sur leurs 31**.... mais quelle est l'origine de cette expression ?

En cherchant un peu, je trouve plusieurs explications :

- une déformation du mot 'trentain' (mais les dates ne semblent pas coincider)
- un jeu de cartes où atteindre 31 était le but
- le fait que le 31 du mois n'arrive que 7 fois (=rarement) dans l'année

et un problème, il semblerait que les cousins du Québec utilisent **se mettre sur son 36**, et là, plus rien ne colle...

Quelqu'un saurait-il trancher en faveur de l'une ou l'autre des explications (ou d'une autre encore que j'aurais zappé) ?

Comment: plus de précisions pour la troisième : il s’agirait du 31 du mois, qui n’arrive que 7 fois par an, date à laquelle les troupiers prusses recevraient un supplément de solde pour terminer le mois. Cela leur permettait évidemment une petite amélioration vestimentaire.

Comment: Je ne suis pas convaincu que la question soit très constructive. Ce sont les explications que l'on trouve généralement, et personne ne semble avoir pouvoir établir avec certitude l'origine.

Comment: Se mettre sur son trente-six est attesté dès 1867 d'après Alain Rey (*Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*) et ne se dit pas qu'au Québec. Alain Rey cite aussi *se mettre sur son trente-deux* en suggérant une *allusion portant sur le jour excédant le compte des jours d'un mois normal (de trente jours)*.  Quant à Claude Duneton (*La puce à l'oreille*) il dit *qu'il est dommage que le sens premier de cette locution soit impénétrable* et qu'il *donne sa langue au chat*!

Comment: @Laure : et nous revoila tombé au [36ème dessous](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/150/pourquoi-trente-six)

Comment: @CédricJulien, sur le site [expressio.fr](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/se-mettre-sur-son-trente-et-un-31.php) décompose 36 en 4 x 9 donc très beau.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Voilà ce que j'ai pu trouver comme explications plausibles (les 2 plus souvent citées et les mieux étayées également) :

**Expression apparue en 1883**

- Le sens se rattache à la valeur intensive de ce nombre, probablement
  au nombre de jours du mois (cf. le dicton trente et un, jour sans
  pain, misère en Prusse, cité par Littré, faisant allusion au fait que
  les troupes cantonnées ne recevaient qu'exceptionnellement le
  supplément d'entretien correspondant au trente et unième jour du
  mois; l'expression sur son **trente-et-un** ferait alors allusion à des
  festivités exceptionnelles liées à ce jour, (*Claude Duneton, La Puce à
  l'oreille, p. 316*).
- On a proposé également de voir dans **trente-et-un** l'altération de trentain
  qualifiant une sorte de drap fin dont la chaîne était composée de
  trente centaines de fils (mot attesté de 1676, Arrêt du Conseil dans
  Littré, à 1892, Guérin [donné à tort comme vivant du XIIe s. au XVe
  siècle dans le dictionnaire d'expressions et locutions de Rey-Chantreau]).

  À l'appui de cette hypothèse Duneton, évoque l'expression québécoise **se mettre sur son trente six** qu'il interprète comme « endosser un habit neuf » [parce que la dénomination
  trente six pouces correspont à notre expression en quatre-vingt dix de
  large, appliquée à du tissu neuf, dans notre système métrique], la
  construction étant expliquée comme une survivance de l'ancienne tournure
  se mettre sus (un drap) « mettre sur soi » (*Rat, Dictionnaire des
  locutions francaise*); **se mettre sur son trente six** est attesté en 1872 (Larch.),
  attesté en québécois seulement en 1881 (d'après la documentation fournie par Cl.
  Poirier, Trésor de la Langue française au Québec; **sur son trente et un** attesté
  en 1884). Cf. aussi la variation **se mettre sur son trente deux** (*1834, Ch.
  Ballard*).

[source](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/trente-et-un)

Answer (score 2):

L'expression est connue pour être de celles dont on ignore l'origine.

Selon le [wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/se_mettre_sur_son_trente-et-un):

> Se mettre sur son trentain. Au moyen-âge, le trentain est un drap de
>   luxe dont la chaîne est composée de trente centaines de fils, et
>   l’expression se mettre sur veut dire revêtir. Attention : l’expression
>   n’a rien à voir avec la Saint-Sylvestre ou le 31 du mois, supposé jour
>   de paie.

Mais sans citer de source, ce qui n'en fait pas une source spécialement plus fiable que d'autres.

Answer (score 1):

Les corps d'armées ont quantité de tenues différentes afin de pouvoir s'adapter à toutes les situations. Ces tenues sont numérotées, et fatalement le N°31 fait référence à une de ces tenues.

En faisant quelques recherches j'ai trouvé plusieurs informations comme quoi la tenue 31 était une tenue de combat ou de prise d'arme. On est donc assez loin de l'habit de cérémonie tel qu'on en parle lorsqu'on *se met sur son 31* (quoique la prise d'arme a quand même quelque chose d'assez pompeux il me semble).

Par curiosité j'ai Googelé les *tenues militaires n°31* et les résultats donnent des images d'uniformes assez classe, qui pourraient être des tenues d'apparat et donc compatible avec l'expression de *se mettre sur son 31*.

Comment: intéressant :) Par contre je n'ai pas spécialement remarqué de différences entre une recherche google "tenues militaires 31" et "tenues militaires N" avec N != 31 ...

Comment: @CédricJulien Ah je n'ai pas pensé à comparer avec d'autre tenues classiques. C'est l'uniforme de la Gendarmerie que j'ai trouvé assez représentatif. Peut-être que la numérotation varie d'un corps d'armée à un autre... Il faudrait l'avis d'un connaisseur de l'armée.

Answer (score 0):

Voilà [une video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r4J_AYrEniY&feature=related) sur les expressions québécoises où l'on parle aussi de cette expression :

> Se mettre sur son 31.

Comment: Bienvenue sur Stack Exchange. Le site cherche à avoir des [réponses aux questions](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer), pas juste des pointeurs vers des réponses. De plus Youtube pourrait effacer cette vidéo. Pourrais-tu résumer les points essentiels dans ta réponse ? Merci.