# What numbers other than 36 have special significance for French speakers?

Tags: expressions, nombres

Autant que je sache, le nombre 36 peut prendre, aux yeux des francophones, un sens spécial pour signifier un grand nombre indéfini. Par exemple, lorsque je me sens dépassé par un nombre incalculable de tâches quotidiennes, en m'éparpillant au-delà de mes capacités, je dirai de façon hyperbolique :

> J'ai comme l'impression de devoir faire **trente-six** choses à la fois !

Qu'est-ce qu'il y a d'autre que 36 comme nombre symbolique ?

Comment: Une autre question sur le trente-six: [Pourquoi trente-six ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/150/364), et une sur le trente-et-un: [Se mettre sur son 31](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1848/364)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *Pour quatre francs six sous* (for very little money)
>
> *Ça casse pas trois pattes à un canard* (it is not extraordinary)
>
> *La semaine des quatre jeudi* (forever on vacation)
>
> *Le mouton à cinq pattes* (something or someone with improbable properties, hard to find if at all)
>
> *Je te reçois cinq sur cinq* (I hear you loud and clear)
>
> *Comme les cinq doigts de la main* (very close family or friends)
>
> *Être La cinquième roue du carrosse* (to feel useless, dispensable)
>
> *Un cinq à sept* (an afternoon affair)
>
> *Cinq minutes douche comprise* (a quickie, a famous French politician's nickname)
>
> *Six pieds sous terre* (Six feet under)
>
> *Pour les jeunes de 7 à 77 ans* (Tintin slogan meaning for all generations)
>
> *Se prendre pour la huitième merveille du monde* (very pretentious)
>
> *Servir le bouillon de onze heures* (to poison someone)
>
> *Treize à la douzaine* (a baker's dozen)
>
> *C'est reparti comme en quatorze* (going to war way too optimistic about a quick victory, allusion to the 1914 fiasco)
>
> *Avoir vingt ans et toutes ses dents* (to be an adult)
>
> *vingt-deux v'là les flics!* (hurry, the cops are coming!)
>
> *Être au trente-sixième dessous* (to be depressed)
>
> *Trente-sept deux le matin* (no fever)
>
> *La génération soixante-huit* (people who were in their 20s in May of 1968)
>
> *Avoir une soixante-douze heures* (for military personnel: to leave for a 3-day week-end)
>
> *Aller à cent à l'heure* (to rush carelessly)
>
> *Attendre cent sept ans*
>
> *Faire les quatre cents coups* (to have a blast)
>
> *Il n'y a pas trente-six mille solutions* (there is only a limited number of possibilities)
>
> *Mille millions de mille sabords!* (Capitaine Haddock's favorite)

And other ones with 36:

> *Tous les 36 du mois* (once in a blue moon)
>
> *Au 36ème dessous* (very depressed)
>
> *Voir 36 chandelles* (stunned)

A famous riddle without actual numbers:

> Vincent mit l'âne dans un pré et s'en vint dans l'autre

Here is a more extensive analysis on this subject:

- Jean-Claude Goyon, [*Les nombres consacrés de l’origine antique et égyptienne de quelques expressions familières*](https://www.mom.fr/image_carto/ServiceImage/loret/loret_0990-5952_1996_bul_10/PDF/loret_0990-5952_1996_bul_10_p7-20.pdf), 1996

Comment: An amazingly comprehensive list of Why-The-Hell-Use-This-Number expressions! Merci. :)

Comment: And 42. 42 is the answer!

Answer (score 4):

**Quatre** a également beaucoup d'usages :

- > Couper les cheveux en quatre

  (Faire trop attention au détails)
- > Se mettre en quatre

  (Faire des efforts considérables)
- > Être plié en quatre

  (Rire puissant)
- > À un de ces quatre

  (Au revoir!)

Comment: *Ne pas y aller par quatre chemins.* qui était cité dans l'autre question sur 36.

Comment: *«Aux quatre coins de l’Hexagone»* me fait toujours sourire. On cite ici et là sur internet, et à juste raison d’ailleurs, qu’*«aux quatre coins de la planète»* n’est pas beaucoup plus avisé.

Answer (score 3):

Pour une liste **impressionnante** voir http://www.maths-rometus.org/mathematiques/maths-et-mots/expressions-avec-des-nombres.asp
google is your friend ;)

Comment: Pour quelques expressions numériques qui sont liées aux nombres *cohérents*, telles que « aux quatre coins du monde », il y en a une autre comme « faire trente-six choses » dont le *pourquoi* m’échappe complètement.

Comment: Concernant 36, vous trouverez des pistes ici : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/150/pourquoi-trente-six.

Comment: @Alone-zee Pourquoi le monde serait-il rectangulaire ? ;)

Comment: @LukeSawczak Il ne s'agirait pas plutôt des quatre points cardinaux : le nord, l'est, le sud et l'ouest ? Et si on reliait ces quatre points en forme de carreau des cartes à jouer ? Nous voilà donc avec un rectangle, quoiqu’en diagonale ! Le nombre 4 (coins) dans l’expression « aux quatre coins du monde » est ainsi, tu en conviendras, un nombre tout ce qu'il y a de plus logique. :) https://photos.app.goo.gl/uQet1gIH54POgXBz1

Comment: Ah, c'est vrai :p Et si on demande pourquoi les quatre points cardinaux, on trouve des fils comme [ceci](https://www.quora.com/Who-Invented-the-cardinal-directions-Whats-the-story-behind-them) ...

Answer (score 1):

- [Vingt-deux (v'la les flics)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/22,_v%27l%C3%A0_les_flics_!)
- Se mettre sur son [trente et un](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/trente-et-un).

Comment: « Se mettre sur son trente et un » est en effet l’une de ces expressions qui nous amènent à se demander d’où diable provient le nombre en question. :)

Comment: Pour moi (je n'ai pas trouvé cette explication en faisant une recherche rapide), le 'trente et un' vient du jour de la saint sylvestre, le 31 décembre, où i lest coutume de bien s'habiller pour fêter la fin de l'année et le début de la nouvelle. Ce qui fait sens c'est qu'à une certaine époque où on ne consommait pas de la même manière qu'actuellement, les gens (proletariat principalement) possédaient assez peu d'habits et gardaient un costume pour les grandes occasions, notamment le 31 décembre.

Comment: @DamienBannerot Je doute que le 31 décembre ait un lien avec l'expression. Comme l'entrée du TLFi le montre, il n'y a pas de consensus sur celle-ci et diverses hypothèses sont suggérées: la plus courante est "être sur son trentain" (un tissu luxueux), d'autres font référence à un jeu de cartes ou le jour de la paie en fin de mois...

Comment: @jlliagre c'est bien pour ça que j'ai apporté mon commentaire en précisant que c'est une reflexion subjective et que je ne l'ai trouvé nul part d'autre.

Comment: Au Québec on dit "Se mettre sur son 36", ce qui rend les tentatives d'explications encore plus hasardeuses...

Answer (score 0):

**deux**

- > c'est à deux pas !

  (sous-entendu : pas loin)
- > c'est à deux pâtés de maisons !

  (sous-entendu : pas loin)
- > j'arrive dans deux minutes

  (sous-entendu :  pas longtemps)
- > je suis là dans deux secondes ...

  (sous-entendu :  pas longtemps)

**trente et un**

> Il était sur son trente et un

(sous-entendu: bien habillé)

Comment: Oui, mais *deux poids, deux mesures*...