# Pourquoi est ce qu'on coupe les cheveux en quatre ?

Tags: sens, expressions, origine-ou-raison

Et pas en dix ou en douze ?
Pourquoi ne pas y aller par "quatre chemins" ?
Est ce le même quatre que dans "tous les quatre matins" ? 
D'où vient le choix du quatre ? Que signifie-t-il ?

Comment: Si vous avez des éléments de votre recherche à partager, veuillez aussi svp. les inclure... Merci !

Answer (score 4):

Il semble que la question veuille couvrir un vaste éventail d’expressions, dans lesquelles le nombre quatre ne porte pas forcément toujours la même valeur symbolique.

---

J’y vais donc en premier lieu avec la ***coupe*** *(ou la* ***fente,*** *selon une variante de l’expression citée)* ***en quatre des cheveux***, qui désigne une trop grande attention à de menus détails.

Il va de soi que le simple fait de fendre un cheveu est une opération qui demande de l’attention, de l’organisation, de la patience, et une ferme foi en la valeur du produit final.

Une coupe dans le sens du cheveu nous donnera deux morceaux. Fendre un cheveu en deux, c’est pareil comme fendre un cheveu tout court.

Si par contre on fait deux coupes, soit le plus petit nombre de coupes multiples, et pour peu que l’on tente d’appliquer simultanément la deuxième coupe aux deux morceaux produits par la première coupe, on se retrouvera avec **quatre** morceaux.

Toute personne ayant la moindre expérience avec la coupe de légumes conviendra que la seconde coupe du cheveu créera de nouveaux défis : il faut en effet, en plus de fendre des morceaux plus petits que l’original, maintenir ensemble, l’une sur l’autre, les deux moitiés obtenues à la première étape.

Donc, **quatre** ne me semble ni complètement inutile, puisqu’il introduit un degré de difficulté à l’opération, ni tout à fait aléatoire ou démesuré, car il résulte simplement d’une deuxième section.

---

Quant à **quatre** en général, voici ce qu’en dit le *Dictionnaire d’expressions et locutions* de *Robert* :

> Exprimant une quantité en rapport avec la structure de notre organisme (l’homme, comme tout mammifère, est un tétrapode), le nombre *quatre* figure dans des locutions exprimant cette structure *(les quatre fers en l’air, faire feu des quatre fers/des quatres pieds, ne pas valoir les quatre fers d’un chien, à quatre pattes)*, mais aussi des objets artificiels organisant symétriquement l’espace *(tiré à quatre épingles, entre quatre planches, ne pas y aller par quatre chemins, être toujours sur les quatres chemins, aux quatre coins de...)* ou dans le temps *(qqch de(s) quatre saisons)*. Intermédiaire entre la notion de minimum *(un, deux)* et celle de pluralité nombreuse, *quatre* peut évoquer à la fois un nombre faible *(c’est à quatre pas, ça vaut quatre sous)* ou important *(dire ses quatre vérités à qqn, faire les quatre volontés de qqn)*. Parfois *quatre* correspond aux redoublement d’organes doubles et signifie « deux personnes » *(entre quat’zyeux, à quatre mains)*.

Suivent plus de détails sur plusieurs autres expressions :

- Quatre à quatre
- Comme quatre
- Un de ces quatre (matins)
- Faire le diables à quatre
- Se mettre en quatre
- Tenir (retenir) à quatre

On pensera aussi à la *semaine des quatre jeudis*, ou à l’exclamation *« Je n’ai pas quatre bras »* <sub>(que l’on hypertrophie chez moi en *« Je ne suis pas une pieuvre »*).</sub>

Parfois, *quatre* est originel à la citation, parfois la valeur variait (ou varie encore) entre différentes versions *(faire les [trente-six](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/150/pourquoi-trente-six) volontés de qqn, ou <sup>Vx</sup> la semaine des trois jeudis, à deux jeudis, à trois jeudis),* parfois aucune valeur numérique n’était (ou n’est) spécifiée *(être toujours sur les chemins, (de) toute(s) saison(s))*.

Chaque expression a son origine et son historique particuliers. Parfois le bon sens a sans doute voulu y mettre quatre plutôt qu’une autre valeur, mais parfois aussi sans doute des concepts plus abstraits, comme l’euphonie ou le simple hasard, ont dû jouer.

Answer (score 2):

Vraiment ?

> - Ça ne casse pas trois pattes à un canard
> - Ça coûte trois francs six sous
> - En deux temps trois mouvements
> - C'est trois fois rien
> - Jamais deux sans trois
> - Haut comme trois pommes

Je ne pense pas qu'on puisse distinguer le 4 des autres nombres, à mon humble avis...

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord avec cette déclaration que le choix de nombres dans *Jamais deux sans trois* soit aléatoire: une fois peut-être un hasard, deux fois indique plus probablement un processus actif générant la chose observée. Si rien n'est fait après deux fois, si on ne cherche pas la cause de l’évènement, une troisième occurrence arrivera inévitablement.

Comment: Un peu de la même manière, les trois pattes du canard sont une de plus que le compte. En casser trois à un canard est déjà faire preuve de ruse. Point besoin d’attendre la quatrième pour être ébahi...

Comment: @Feelew Je suis d'accord avec votre argument sur le canard, c'est factuel. Pas tout à fait d'accord avec votre premier argument par contre, puisque si l'on se réfère à l'anglais *Fool me once, shame on you, fool me twice, shame on me*, une seule fois suffit. On aurait très bien pu dire "jamais un sans deux", mais on ne l'a pas fait.

Comment: *Fool me once...* ne fait pas référence aux mêmes choses que *Jamais deux sans trois*. Dans la vie, beaucoup de petits événements fortuits et sans importance surviennent. Ce sont eux qui sont ciblés en français. On n’agira pas forcément à la première instance, mais le dicton nous prévient qu’une troisième fois surviendra si on en observe deux. L’anglais discute d'évènements plus sérieux, reliés à la fraude ou à la ruse.

Comment: Sorry for hopping on the hair-splitting bandwagon but I've always equated "Jamais 2 sans 3" with "Things (good or bad) happen/come in threes."

Answer (score 2):

Pour n'importe quoi, le plus facile est de couper en deux et par répétition en quatre (ou huit mais personne ne visualise immédiatement 8 parts, 4 si)
C'est donc le partage type que chacun peut facilement proposer, avec un gâteau par exemple.(je suis sûr que vous visualisez en ce moment un gâteau coupé en 4)
Mais il faut une certaine épaisseur. S'agissant des cheveux : même pas imaginable.
Quatre est donc la quantité immédiatement visualisable qui peut déjà évoquer 'beaucoup'.